# Rejecting received message because of the listener container having been stopped in the meantime:

Tags: jms

I am stuck with this exception printing continuously after my JMS listener is stopped. After deployment the log file for two days was around 6.2GB.

```
2017-08-01 12:14:36.436  WARN 4456 --- [er (4102308050)] o.s.j.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer   : Rejecting received message because of the listener container having been stopped in the meantime: ObjectMessage={ Header={ JMSMessageID={ID:EMSATIBDEV0.291559497D151:2A78089} JMSDestination={Queue[JP.PROGRAMGUIDE.DATALOAD.SUB.Q]} JMSReplyTo={null} JMSDeliveryMode={PERSISTENT} JMSRedelivered={true} JMSCorrelationID={null} JMSType={null} JMSTimestamp={Tue Aug 01 12:03:23 JST 2017} JMSDeliveryTime={Tue Aug 01 12:03:23 JST 2017} JMSExpiration={0} JMSPriority={4} } Properties={ JMSXDeliveryCount={Integer:3} } Object={com.company.programguide.dataload.model.vo.ProgramGuideDataloadDetailsVo@66820b} }
```

For Event listening I have this function which implements ApplicationListener

```
@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(ProgramGuideManagerEvent<String> event) {
    log.trace("In ProgramGuideManagerEventListener");
    synchronized (syncObject) {
       if (event.isError()) {
        errorCount++;
        if (errorCount >= maxErrorCount) {
            log.error("Maximum sequential errors [errorCount=" + errorCount+ "] occurred.  Listener will be stopped.");
            String listenerName = (String) event.getSource();
            Map<String, JmsListenerEndpointRegistry> map = context.getBeansOfType(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
            Set<String> set = map.keySet();
            // JMS Listeners
            for (String key : set) {
                JmsListenerEndpointRegistry value = map.get(key);
                if (value != null) {
                    Set<String> listeners = value.getListenerContainerIds();
                    for (String name : listeners) {
                        if (name.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(listenerName)) {
                            MessageListenerContainer jms = value.getListenerContainer(name);
                            jms.stop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        errorCount = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: how is this related to spring-batch?

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko Sorry. Was executing for a long time along with an spring batch.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't stop the container in the message delivery thread. Spawn a new thread to stop the container. You'll probably see a handful of errors, but it should stop fairly quickly. For extra cleanliness, mark an atomic Boolean as true to indicate the container has been issued a stop so you can throw a runtime exception next delivery and prevent additional stop threads being spawned.